# How to implement sorting in EXTJS Grid

Tags: grid, extjs4

I am facing a problem in extjs grid . I have two grid column one is name and another is displayName but I want to sorting by name in both column means I displayName as well as name. When user apply sort in both column parameters pass by grid is sort= name in both case.

```
[
        {
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            shortable: true
        },
        {
            header: 'DisplyName',
            dataIndex: 'displayName',
            shortable: true
        }
    ]
```

Comment: in your code there is a mistake its not shortable its sortable

Comment: and i am not clear can you clearly tell about your problem

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can do that in [beforesort event](http://docs.php-admin.com/extjs4/docs/index.html#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-beforesort) handle function of grid's store.
Like this:

```js
  // here is the key point
 listeners: {
     beforesort: function(st, sorters) {
       console.log(sorters, st);
       if (sorters.length == 1 && sorters[0].property == 'displayName') {
         sorters[0].property = 'name';
       }
     }
   }
   // here is the key point end
```

[a live example](http://runjs.cn/code/a0nf75qj)